# "Unexpected end of JSON input" error when deploying Next 14 app to Vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

I am building a Next 14 app and deploying it to Vercel. I have a route handler that is running 100% smoothly in the dev environment, but is failing when I deploy it to Vercel.

Here is the request

```js
//app/page.js
export default async function Home() {
  const response = await fetch(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FRONTEND_URL}/api/test`,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ data: 'test string' }),
      next: { revalidate: 24 },
    }
  )
  const test = await response.json()

  console.log('TEST Request >> ', test)
//...
}
```

And here is the route handler

```js
//app/api/test/route.js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function POST(request, response) {
  // Get JSON payload
  const data = await request.json()

  // Return Response
  return NextResponse.json(
    {
      data,
    },
    {
      status: 200,
    }
  )
}
```

So when the home page loads, it calls the route handler and logs the response. This works as it should in dev. But when I deploy to Vercel, it gives me this error.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5329:19)
    at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5300:27)
    at fullyReadBody (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1447:9)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async specConsumeBody (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5309:7)
    at async Home (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:1:2868)
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5329:19)
    at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5300:27)
    at fullyReadBody (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1447:9)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async specConsumeBody (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5309:7)
    at async Home (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:1:2868)
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5329:19)
    at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5300:27)
    at fullyReadBody (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1447:9)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async specConsumeBody (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5309:7)
    at async Home (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:1:2868)
```

I have no clue why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem may come from the ` env ` variable, you must have two  ` .env ` files, one for dev and another one for production, in dev it may be ` localhost:3000 ` or anything else and in production must be a valid url. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the issue. My env variable in prod is https://ron-shirks.vercel.app and it even works when I run it in postman. So I put the post request in postman and it worked fine, and I did it in dev and it worked fine, it just won’t work in prod